# Google cloud sql instance unknown error

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have an Cloud-SQL instance restarted by itself for no reason.  In any case, the restart failed with the following error:

`2018-02-08 16:33:22.552 CST
+ exec /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/mysql/my.cnf
Expand all | Collapse all {
 insertId:  "s=1eb5f90cdd6e4332b0bfd1260e067581;i=21ee;b=4ff35c4064f348848019b0498c04fcfd;m=50ef121;t=564baffd724ea;x=3528d562989af59-0@b1a"

 logName:  "projects/xxxxxxx/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err"

 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-02-08T22:33:31.058969560Z"

 resource: {
  labels: {
   database_id:  "xxxxxx:yyyyyyyy"

   project_id:  "yyyyyyy"

   region:  "us-central"

  }
  type:  "cloudsql_database"

 }
 severity:  "ERROR"

 textPayload:  "+ exec /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/mysql/my.cnf"

 timestamp:  "2018-02-08T22:33:22.552734Z"

}`

Looking at Cloud-SQL instance console, all action links were greyed out and my instance is showing a yellow warning sign. The operation and logs on the console displayed:

`Feb 8, 2018, 3:50:48 PM Restart  An unknown error occurred.`

Click on users and database tab, I've got this:

`Users/Database cannot be loaded from MySQL at this time. Make sure your instance is runnable.`

I am unable to restart the instance via console or gcloud cl:

`$ gcloud sql instances restart xxxxxxxx`


`The instance will shut down and start up again immediately if its
activation policy is "always." If "on demand," the instance will start
 up again when a new connection request is made.
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.restart) HTTPError 409: The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request.`

Query using MySQL workbench via ip is still working but my Firebase Cloud Function was not able to access the MySQL DB via socket path.

Not sure what to do to get back my instance, shall I just create another instance and try to restore?

Comment: The solution to your Cloud SQL instance getting stuck in a bad state where you no longer have control of it is to control Google Cloud Platform support, either through your support package or the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) as you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

With Refrence to [Google Issues Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73128574)

**It has been fixed.**

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73128574) they will re-open to examine.